# Populating update statement from results of select

Tags: sql, groovy

I have a scenario like this:

I need to update some rows in a batch from a select, here is an approximate code I have

```
String queryText = "select " + config.fields.join(",") +" from myTable where myfield > 0"

String updateSqlText = "update otherTable set ("+ config.oterhTable.fields.join("=?,") + " ) where ID=?";

// just an example for insert
String insertSqlText = "insert into otherTable ("+ config.oterhTable.fields.join(",") + " ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,? ...)";

def updateCounts = otherSql.withBatch(100, updateSqlText) { ps ->
    riskSql.eachRow(queryText){ row ->

    if (row.ID == 0){
            // this doesn't work, but I want to do something similar
            otherSql.execute(insertSqlText, row)
        } else {
            // this doesn't work, I need to convert to list. The error I get: aught: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to convert between com.sun.proxy.$Proxy6 and JAVA_OBJECT
            ps.addBatch(row, row.SUD_ID)
        }
    }
}
```

the query result for queryText is large, so I can't call .rows() to get a list of results. Is there an easier way to make a list of the rows closure? Basically I need all the fields in there to map to my prepared statement.

Comment: It's not very clear exactly what you are trying to do, or where it is failing. Does the code you posted work, but you are trying to optimize it?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, I can't pass a row from .eachRow into .addBatch. What I need is the conversion of row into a list

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
Here is a solution that avoids using `eachRow`, instead using `rows` with a page and offset. This should allow you to avoid the large result set problem.

```
    def count = sql.firstRow('select count(*) as c from <table>').c
    def page = 0
    def pageSize = 10

    while (page * pageSize < count) {
        sql.rows('select * from <table>', page, pageSize).each { GroovyRowResult row ->
            def values = row.collect { key, value -> value }
            println values  // <- values is a List
        }
        ++page
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I am trying that and it gives me strange error on the collect call - Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name value. SQL by itself works and returns results.

Comment: I think the eachRow returns GroovyResultSet, not GroovyRowResult.

Comment: You are correct about the `GroovyResultSet` when using `eachRow`. I updated the solution taking a different tack, instead using `rows` with a page/offset. See if it works for you.

Comment: That's actually the way I tried to do it, but this requires two queries and by the time we are into the second query the count can change. I did something different instead, I'll show in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did so I don't have a double query:

```
def resultList = []
row.getMetaData().getColumnCount().times{
    resultList.add(row.getAt(it))
}

resultList.add(row.SUD_ID)
sql.executeUpdate(updateSqlText, resultList)
```

Just went through the result set and added it to an array.